# Load login / register block in custom template

Tags: 8, blocks

I've created my own homepage template [`page--front.html.twig`] and want to add the drupal default login and register form. I was looking for something like

```
{% include 'themes/bootstrap/templates/block--system-login.html.twig' %}
```

But it looks like none of these kind of blocks exist.

If I go to `user/login` and take a look into the source code (with devel enabled) I also do not see any block hint:

```
<div class="region region-content">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'block' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--flowers-content.html.twig
   * block--system-main-block.html.twig
   x block--system.html.twig
   * block.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/block--system.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig' -->
<form class="user-login-form" data-drupal-selector="user-login-form" action="/user/login" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

How can I add the login and register form in my (homepage)-Template? I did not find any useful information related to Drupal 8.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user/login` **page** is different from the the user login **block**. To add the user login form to an arbitrary page, then you would need to add the user login **block** to a region you want, and configure it to display only on the front page. This can be done using the Block administration page ([documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block)).